# WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged doesn't work with GZip

Tags: .net, compression

In order to use WebClient with compressed content I have extended it and changed the default WebRequest as follows:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    var req = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    return req;
}
```

This works fine, except that now the DownloadProgressChanged event is not firing, even though the Content-Length header is appropriately set by the server (the server is not chunking the response).

Why is this?

EDIT: Actually, the DownloadProgressChanged event is firing, but it always shows a percentage of 0 until the download is complete, when it shows 100. What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Is it using HTTPS? Sometimes the Content-Lengh gets encrypted so the browser won't know before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not too sure, but I can see you didnt implement this all the way.  Perhaps thats why... you might be missing headers.  Reflector shows a bit more code.  Maybe the second line of the method is what you need.

```
protected virtual WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    this.CopyHeadersTo(request);
    if (this.Credentials != null)
    {
        request.Credentials = this.Credentials;
    }
    if (this.m_Method != null)
    {
        request.Method = this.m_Method;
    }
    if (this.m_ContentLength != -1L)
    {
        request.ContentLength = this.m_ContentLength;
    }
    if (this.m_ProxySet)
    {
        request.Proxy = this.m_Proxy;
    }
    if (this.m_CachePolicy != null)
    {
        request.CachePolicy = this.m_CachePolicy;
    }
    return request;
}
```

Comment: I call base.GetWebRequest(), so all that stuff is taken care of. In any event, all of the headers on both sides are being sent correctly. The only issue is the download progress.